# Select only 10 characters from table

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm trying to make a news table, with the latest news from my site.
In my news site, I only want to show the first 20 words from the table (with a "Read more")

I'm selecting my table like this:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT news.*, login.firstname, login.lastname, login.pisture AS picture FROM news LEFT JOIN login ON login.Id = nyheder.writer ORDER BY news.Id DESC";
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried?

Comment: for performance reasons, you may be better off with a column that has those 20 words in it.  If you don't, all selects would have to do parsing logic to figure out the length of the data, then determine if you should do a substring() or not.

Comment: It's probably going to be quicker and easier to find the 20th space character in C# than in SQL.

Comment: In your title it says you want 10 characters, in the question you talk about 20 words - what is it?

Comment: I just want to show either 10 or 20 words (dosen't matter that much). I just want to learn how to do it :)
For now i havent tried anything yet, because I dont know the command. But i thought the command would be something like: "Select 10 chars FROM news" and so on.. But i guess its a bit more complicated

Comment: @PeterJakobsen - Characters and words are two different things! It seems like you want *words* not *characters*. And as Damien said, it's probably quicker and easier to do it in C#. Take a look at [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b873y76a.aspx) and then [Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb503062.aspx) and [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/57a79xd0.aspx) after that.

Answer (score 3):

If you use sql server, try to add SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) to your query:
e.g. if you want to get the 20 characters from the "content" field in "news" table:

```
SELECT news.*, 
SUBSTRING ( news.content, 1, 20) as short_content ,
login.firstname, login.lastname, 
login.pisture AS picture 

FROM news LEFT JOIN login ON login.Id = nyheder.writer 
ORDER BY news.Id DESC
```

If you use another database like oracle try "substr".

Answer (score 1):

Usually to retrieve a short part of a long text in database, you should use a string function like as this:

```
SELECT LEFT(news.newsText, 20)+"..." as shortText ,... from ...
```

the LEFT function works in SqlServer and Ms Access database. for other databases there is an equivalent function.  if you want you can check also the length of news content and add the "..." trailing string only if it is trimmed.